# Create a required parameter in the URL route with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a very simple routing for angular (using ui-router) set up like that:

```
$stateProvider

    .state("master", {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/{tenantName}"            
    })

    .state("master.home", {
        url: "",
    })

    .state("master.login", {
        url: "/login"
    })
```

Now I want that if there is no parameter in the url, it does not match any state and goes to a default state. But I have 2 problems with that:

1. master.home matches the url with domain only e.g. `domain.com` and I want the parameter to be obligatory (domain.com/hello). The only way I have found to do that is to put a non-empty regular expression there, but I hope there is a better way.
2. I don't know how to make a proper default state. It seems that the only option is to create a default state with "" url (after the 1 is fixed) and add the .otherwise to redirect to the url of that state.

Answer (score 0):

you can have an otherwise state

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // if the path doesn't match any of the urls you configured
    // otherwise will take care of routing the user to the specified url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');

    // Example of using function rule as param
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
        ... some advanced code...
    });
})
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: Is it somehow special this otherwise state? Because it did not work for me, I guess I'll still have to do url otherwise?

Comment: I have not seen that in the docs, and it does not work for me... I also don't know how to make parameter required

Comment: ha, u r using angular ui-router?

Comment: Yes, I am, it's in the tags, I should have added to the header/body I guess as well

Comment: Yes, I know this solution as I wrote in the body, I thought it's possible to not use .otherwise somehow. And I am more interested in the "required" param really, since it matches for domain only which I don't want.

Comment: not sure if I understand.  you can just move the home to otherwise and problem solved.

Comment: also your url scheme is a bit strange.  why do you have an abstract with a param and then child states have the same scheme but as a constant route?

Comment: I want to have /company1/login, /company2/home, etc. for a multi-tenant environment where default routes (without company) are not correct. So I want to ensure that the company name exists.

Comment: hmm.  does that make sense though?  how would you know a company name for a client that hasn't logged in yet?

Comment: your logic is more like server-side

Comment: Client can only logon to their own company, so it has to be known beforehand. They will get a url in email or SMS e.g.

Comment: yeah sure, but you can abstract this and unify all routes.  at the end, you know who is logging in.